# Fourier transform of sine function

Tags: fourier-transform, mathematics

While solving the Fourier transformation of a sine wave (say $h(t)=A\sin (2 \pi f_0 t)$) in time domain, we get two peaks in frequency domain in frequency space with a factor of $(A/2)j$ with algebraic sum of delta function for $f+f_0$ and $f-f_0$ frequency, where $j$ is the imaginary unit.

My question is,

1. The Fourier Transform of odd function is imaginary in frequency domain, so what is its physical significance if it is a imaginary space.
2. As delta function have unit area what does $A/2$ means which comes under calculation. Does it mean delta function for two peaks have area $A/2$ now?
3. Why do we get two peaks such that sine wave has only one frequency. And what does it show physically for a physicist?

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 4):

For a simple $\sin$ or $\cos$ function, I find it easiest to understand by just remembering their definitions:
$$
A\sin(\omega t) = \frac{A}{2i}\left(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t} \right) 
$$
Now you can clearly see where the two coefficients come from. You have
$$a_{\omega} = \frac{A}{2i} = -\frac{A}{2}i $$
and
$$a_{-\omega} = -\frac{A}{2i} = \frac{A}{2}i$$
So you can see how you need two coefficients to make a $sin$ wave out of a linear combination of $e^{in\omega t}$s.

For the integral transformation you then necessarily need delta functions to pick out exactly those two points from the complex plane:
\begin{align*}
\sin(t) \propto \int \Big(\delta(\omega-1) + \delta(\omega+1) \Big)e^{i\omega t}\mathrm{d}\omega = e^{it} + e^{-it}
\end{align*}

Comment: but what do they associate when we actually write in Fourier space of it. And would love if you answer my other query.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention the $\delta$-function, a periodic signal can be reconstructed with the fourier series. Are you asking about the integral transform? I'm not sure if there's a good physical interpretation of the $i$. Maybe you find it useful to think of summing over $A \cos(\omega n t + \varphi)$, so instead of summing over $\sin$ and $\cos$ you sum over cosines with phase shifts which is where the $i$ comes in.

Comment: Yeah i mean i would like to know what happens in fourier transformation of sine and cosine waves and its physical meaning in that space, if you talk about cosine wave. And by delta function i mean when you find its fourier transform you get it as a result.

Comment: I added a little bit at the end of my answer, I hope this is what you're asking about.